How to create Full Transparent Emissive Shader in Eevee(Raytracing)?
I want to make lights using Geometry, Textures and Emission Shader, but I want these lights(geometry) to be completely transparent and invisible to the camera, how can I do this using shaders?


Disable the Camera option in the Object panel > Visibility > Ray Visibility?

@moonboots I'm using Blender 4.2 and Eevee with ray tracing and disabling Ray Visibility disables the light completely, I tried it in Cycles as well and got the same results or did I do it wrong?

it should work in Cycles, in Eevee Emission won't work by default, you need to create a Light Probe > Volume and Bake the indirect lighting. Do you plan to use Cycles or Eevee?

I'm currently using Eevee but I'd like to know how to do it in Cycles as well. I looked at "Baking the lightning to a Light Probe" but it doesn't give the detail I want.

Perhaps it would be a useful information to be put in the question directly instead of somewhere in the comments that you want to do it in EEVEE, not (only) Cycles. Right now your question only asks for hiding the object from the camera which is a simple task. And since @moonboots already provided a working solution for EEVEE but it's not sufficient in your opinion, you should specify what exactly you need to be content.

@GordonBrinkmann Yes, you're right, I'm not very familiar with StackExcange sorry about that. I added more details to the title and explained why Light Probe is not enough in the comments of moonboots answer.

In Cycles to make the object invisible, go into the Object panel > Visibility > Ray Visibility > disable Camera:

In Eevee, until Blender 4.2, by default an emissive material won't project any light on the scene, but you can create a Light Probe > Volume that encompass your scene, set its resolution so that it is accurate enough:

Then Bake Indirect Lighting in the Render panel and hide (or even remove) the emissive object:

Since 4.2 you can activate the Raytracing option and the Emissive object will project its light on the scene, but I'm not sure how you could make invisible...

Thanks for the answer. I tried it in Cycles and it works, I need something like this in Eevee. Unfortunately, Light Probe workaround is not powerful enough.

powerful in what sense?

In terms of detail and resolution. I couldn't find the 'Bake' section where it is shown in the images,I think they placed it in the data section in Blender 4.2.I tried a few times with Light Probe but it is not strong enough in terms of detail and resolution.I can increase the resolution of Light Probe but I think this will cause performance loss. For example, create two Planes with a width of 1 meter and leave a 1 cm gap between them, and add a texture with high detail and emission to one of the Planes and try Baking it,the details in the Texture of the emission will be lost.

If you choose Eevee I guess you need to find a trick

at least I learned how light probes work and that Eevee doesn't support transparent emission by default while Cycle does, thanks for your answer.

The last Eevee is different so there may be a way but I don't know it...

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
